# Why does function reassign 2Darray argument as sideeffect from calling the latter

Tags: javascript

When I run the third line alone and log test2darr it returns a 2D array filled with 6's in a 3x3 matrix
But when I run the fourth line and log test2darr again, it returns:
 [4, 5, 4]
 ​
[5, 6, 5]​
[4, 5, 4]
 (as well as for secondtest)
Though it should return the same array of 6's for test2darr and on assign the 2d array to secondtest

```
const n = 3;
const filler = new Array(n * n);

const test2darr = fill2DarrFromArr(filler.fill(6));

const secondtest = pileReduce(test2darr);
```

Here is my code for fill2DarrFromArr and pileReduce:

```
function pileReduce(_cells) { 

    _cells = fillEmpty(_cells);

    for (let j = 0; j < _cells.length; j++) { //The Algorithm itself is not important 
        for (let i = 0; i < _cells.length; i++) { // But there might be some assignment problem that I missed
            if (_cells[j][i] >= 4) {
                _cells[j][i] = _cells[j][i] - 4;

                if (j !== _cells.length - 1) _cells[j + 1][i]++;
                if (j !== 0) _cells[j - 1][i]++;
                if (i !== _cells.length - 1) _cells[j][i + 1]++;
                if (i !== 0) _cells[j][i - 1]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return _cells;
}

function fill2DarrFromArr(_arr) { 
     let sideLength = Math.sqrt(_arr.length);
     let out = create2DArr(sideLength, sideLength);
    for (let j = 0; j < sideLength; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < sideLength; i++) {
            out[j][i] = _arr[j * sideLength + i];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

function create2DArr(_n, _m) {
    let _arr = new Array(_n);

    for (let j = 0; j < _m; j++) {
        _arr[j] = new Array(_m);
    }
    return _arr;
}

function fillEmpty(_arr) {
    for (let j = 0; j < _arr.length; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
            if (!_arr[j][i]) _arr[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return _arr;
}
```

Comment: The definition of fillempty is missing

Comment: I added fillEmpty to the definitions. Though It wouldn't change much if that line wasn't there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an array into a function doesn't create a copy of that array. Your functions are modifying the contents of the passed arrays, therefore they have side effects.